# jscrollpane not working

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

I am hoping someone can tell what I am doing wrong. I can't get the jscrollpane to work on a page on my site. Just text with a box > very simple idea but the scrollbars are either nonexistent or the default.

Thank you
Debra

Comment: I forgot to add the link to the page.

Comment: http://www.nettlesdesign.com/client/RCWsite2011/about.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the javascript files for jScrollPane and the mousewheel plugin aren't available on your server:

[image: Screenshot of the network tab on Chrome when loading the example page]